# Python, I'm repeating myself a lot when it comes to for loops and there must be a better way

Tags: python, for-loop, dry

Lets say I have three lists and I need to iterate through them and do some stuff to the contents.

The three lists are `streaks_0`, `streaks_1`, and `streaks_2`. For each list, I need to use different values specific to each list. For example, `streak_0_num0s` will not work in the `streaks_1` for loop.

Is there a way to make these three for loops into one or at least a way to clean this up?

```
for number in streaks_0:
    if number == 0:
        streak_0_num0s += 1
    elif number != 0:
        streak_0_sum += number
streak_0_average = (streak_0_sum / (len(streaks_0) - streak_0_num0s))

for number in streaks_1:
    if number == 0:
        streak_1_num0s += 1
    elif number != 0:
        streak_1_sum += number
streak_1_average = (streak_1_sum / (len(streaks_1) - streak_1_num0s))

for number in streaks_2:
    if number == 0:
        streak_2_num0s += 1
    elif number != 0:
        streak_2_sum += number
streak_2_average = (streak_2_sum / (len(streaks_2) - streak_2_num0s))
```

Comment: of course: use a list of dictionaries for instance. But that would be best suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is the site to ask for code improvements

Comment: Unrelated to your question: reduce "elif number != 0" to a simple "else".

Comment: You can use threading to make them all run at the same time if that appeals to you.

Comment: ^^^ that's pretty pointless here

Comment: instead of elif...  in the first loop else is shorter

Comment: a list of lists may help with streaks[i] when is in range len(streaks)

Comment: I was initially skeptical of @Jean-FrançoisFabre's close vote, but skimming the code, answers, and comments, the sheer number of improvements to be made leads me to agree that this question is much better suited for [CodeReview.SE]. The issues go far beyond the single question that's been focused on, and the code would benefit greatly from a full review in an environment where pointing out any issue you see is encouraged. (I'm assuming you're a beginner, Ari, so don't take that personally. But you do have a lot to learn here.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Why not use a function?

```
def get_average(streaks):
    streak_0_num0s = 0
    streak_0_sum = 0

    for number in streaks:
        if number == 0:
            streak_0_num0s += 1
        elif number != 0:
            streak_0_sum += number
    streak_0_average = (streak_0_sum / (len(streaks) - streak_0_num0s))
    print(streak_0_average)

get_average(streaks01)
get_average(streaks02)
get_average(streaks03)
```

Comment: A minor quibble, but surely your function as written should be named `print_average` instead of `get_average`, since it prints the result instead of returning it? Of course, having a function automatically print its result is usually a code smell anyway...

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Or better yet, have `get_average` actually return the value and put the `print` outside it.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen very true, I basically took his code as written and made a quick example. But yes, it really should say print_average, or as jpmc26 pointed out, return the results and then do something with it

Answer (score 11):

Your code can be easily simplified with a function like the below one:

```
def calculate_avg(lst):
    return sum(lst)/(len(lst)-lst.count(0))
```

or this one if you prefer:

```
def calculate_avg(lst):
    return sum(lst) / len([l for l in lst if l != 0])
```

and here's a little usage example:

```
streaks = [
    [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0],
    [0, 0, 6, 7, 8, 0, 0]
]

for index, streak in enumerate(streaks):
    print("avg(streak{})={}".format(str(index).zfill(2), calculate_avg(streak)))
```

Answer (score 7):

Write a function, that you can call multiple times:

```
def calculate_average(values):
    non_zeros = 0
    sum = 0

    for value in values:
        if value != 0:
            sum += value
            non_zeros += 1
    return sum / non_zeros

streak_0_average = calculate_average(streaks_0)
streak_1_average = calculate_average(streaks_1)
streak_2_average = calculate_average(streaks_2)
```

Answer (score 5):

As the others already said: When you find you repeat yourself a lot of times: try to create a function that can be re-used.

However it's always a good idea to have a look around and see if someone already implemented such a function. In your case you could use [`numpy.mean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) (`numpy` is a 3rd party module) or [`statistics.mean`](https://docs.python.org/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) (`statistics` is a built-in module in python 3.4+).

The only thing they don't do by default is excluding the zeros, so you have to do that yourself:

```
import numpy as np

def average(streaks):
    streaks = np.asarray(streaks)
    streaks_without_zeros = streaks[streaks != 0]
    return np.mean(streaks_without_zeros)

streaks_0 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3]
print(average(streaks_0))  # 2.2857142857142856
```

or:

```
import statistics

def average(streaks):
    streaks_without_zeros = [streak for streak in streaks if streak != 0]
    return statistics.mean(streaks_without_zeros)

streaks_0 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3]
print(average(streaks_0))  # 2.2857142857142856
```